# Rewrite Rule In ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, iis

I use a rewrite rule in IIS in single page app and using angular ui router to serve my project but when I send request to api service it not call it and redirect to the page that I put in the action of the rule and the response return me with HTML page in string format that is the Single Page Body returned to me instead of the expected data that I want from consuming the service.

```
<rule name="HomeRule" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="po" ignoreCase="true" />  
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions> 
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/Pages/MasterPage.html" />
  </rule>
```

please any one help to fix this issue 
thanks in advance

Comment: when you want to implement the rewrite URL you need to remind 2 things 1. You need to install the URL Rewrite 2.0 in your IIS and 2. You should be adding your `Basehref` into your HTMl

Comment: i really make this steps but any request i send it give me response with html page and not return me the expected data that i want from this request

Comment: can you able to hit the api ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at what this is saying.

```
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
</conditions>
```

With `MatchAll` logical grouping, its saying only execute the rule if the filename is not a `directory` and not a `filename`. Is that what you really want?